# terraform aws_imagebuilder_component needs to be replaced because of script line endings changed

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform "image_builder" module which has an `aws_imagebuilder_component` resource loading the `commands` from a `ps1` script file like so:

```
resource "aws_imagebuilder_component" "iissetup" {
  data = yamlencode({
    phases = [{
      name = "build"
      steps = [{
        name   = "setup-iis"
        action = "ExecutePowerShell"
        inputs = {
          commands = split("\n", file("${path.module}/scripts/iis_setup.ps1"))
        }
        onFailure = "Abort"
      }]
    }]
    schemaVersion = 1.0
  })
  name        = "msf-setup-iis"
  description = "Clean up default IIS Site"
  platform    = "Windows"
  version     = "0.0.2"
}
```

When I deploy my infrastructure by referencing the module locally - i.e. `D:/modules/module`

and then decide to switch to the same module but hosted on git (azure git repo)
terraform complains that it needs to redeploy my component as the line endings have changed.

```
module "image_bulder" {
  source      = "git::https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_git/MyTeam.IaC.Modules//modules/image_builder?ref=main"
  # source      = "D:\\modules\\image_builder"
  ...
}
```

when I run `terraform apply` again I see that terraform will recreate the component:

[image]

Is there a way to get around that issue so that terraform ignores those line engines and I do not have to recreate my component when I switch from local to git module?

Comment: Can you switch between line endings in your IDE if you are using one, i.e., instead of LF use CRLF or vice versa?

Comment: @MarkoE thank you for your response. Currently I am using LF, I will try switching to CRLF and report back. I know that git converts LF to CRLF when checking out files so switching to CRLF might do it.

Comment: @MarkoE, switching to CRLF resolved the issue. Apologies that it took a while to respond.

Comment: Ha, no worries, glad I could help. :)